# Unable to escape single quotes db2 sql query run via shell script

Tags: sql, shell, db2

There is probably a very simple solution to this, but I've tried every variation I could think of and still not able get rid of the error:

I'm running this via a shell script:

```
su - myid -c 'db2 -v "EXPORT TO '/tmp/file.out' OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL| select A, B, C FROM mytable where C = '' and ( F = 1 or F = 2 or F = 3 or F = 4 ) "'
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "=   and ( status" was found following "mytable
where C".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ANSI-quoted string if you are using `bash`:

```
su - myid -c $'db2 -v "EXPORT TO \'/tmp/file.out\'...'
```

in which you can quote a single quote using `\'`. In POSIX shells, you'll have to use double-quotes, and quote the embedded double-quotes:

```
su - myid -c "db2 -v \"EXPORT TO '/tmp/file.out' ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here's my updated query:

```
su - myid -c 'db2 -v "EXPORT TO '/tmp/file.out' OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL| select A, B, C FROM mytable where C = '\'''\''  and ( F = 1 or F = 2 or F = 3 or F = 4 ) "'
```

I had to replace the single **''** with **'\'''\''**  <---those are all single quotes